# How do I make a table in the left side of the screen with Boostrap css?

Tags: css

I have a website and I'm trying to make a table in the left side of my screen in css But when I type the class span8 or more, my table doesn't move to the left side.

It doesn't work.

Comment: we can't help you without code (or markup, in this case).

Answer (score 0):

You can add the classes .pull-left and .pull-right to float-align an element with Bootstrap.

```
<table class="table pull-left">
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
  <tr>
</table>
```